# Hibernate keyword Search

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-search

E.g, when I use this DSL for searching:

```
Query query = queryBuilder.keyword().onField("person").matching("man").createQuery();
```

I want the results just include the single word `man` on field `person`, without the results like `He is a man` on the field. How can i do?

Someone have clues??? Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how free text search works. You cannot say it should only match if the search term matches and there is only a single term. The whole point of a free text search engine is to find matches within a given text corpus. If your field person contains once "man" and once "he is a man" you get a match for both (unless you index the fields un-analyzed). The difference is in the score.

Comment: Thx so much for the response. But I can't index the field un-analyzed. U said the difference is in the score, can u give me a example for filtering the results by score?

Comment: Or can I use a dynamic filter to control the length of results?(If I search "man", the lenght of result should be 3)

Answer (score 1):

In your case I'd stick with standard Hibernate query (in HQL it'd be something similar to `from MyClass mc where mc.person = "man"`). You can find more info about HQL [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html)

If HQL is not an option, consider using JPA criteria API.

As @Hardy mentioned in his answer, your use case does not match with full text search approach.

Comment: Then maybe use JPA criteria api?

Comment: For some restrictions, I can't use HQL in my project. I wrote a filter for the result after executing the query of Hibernate search. Ty for your response.*